# CSS positioning looks very different in dev tools

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive web app. In my dev tools I've toggled to laptop with touch (1280 x 950) and it looks very different than what I see on my screen when I'm not using dev tools. I double checked my screen size, by typing window.innerWidth // returns 1280
window.innerHeight // returns 950

This is the css:

```
.video-player{
    position: relative;
    top: 20vh;
}
```

On the standard (non dev tools view, the image video looks fine and is positioned to the point that I want it), see:

```
https://image.ibb.co/hKSF75/Screen_Shot_2017_08_02_at_2_05_12_PM.png
```

On the dev tools toggle 1280 x 950 (the image looks like does not look like it has been positioned to near the top of yellow bar above it), see:

```
https://image.ibb.co/htpZ0Q/Screen_Shot_2017_08_02_at_2_05_01_PM.png
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Sorry I wish we had more information to better answer your question.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but with dev tools open, if it's at the bottom of the window, it will change the `vh`, so `20vh` will change.

Answer (score 0):

`vh` is a percentage measure of the viewport's height.

When you open the developer tools, the viewport gets smaller (to hold the dev tools). This is what is causing your positioning to change.